# UITableViewController overriding scrolling behavior when keyboard appears

Tags: keyboard, scroll, overriding, uitextview, uitableview

In a UITableViewController, the default behavior when the keyboard appears is to scroll the edited text field just above the keyboard like below, which is really annoying when you need to edit several text fields in a row (in this case enter the password after the login info).

(Rats! Won't let me post images - but this would have shown a UserName text field cell automatically scrolled just above the keyboard, with the next Password entry field hidden below the keyboard)

Instead I want it to behave like the Apple's own Settings.app and scroll higher so the next text field is also visible and ready for the following edit, like this:

(and Apple's own Settings.app screenshot would have shown the same Username field cell being edited, automatically scrolled further up so the Password field below it shows up also - you can try it for yourself).

How can I override UITableViewController to achieve the same effect, i.e. scrolling the text fields one text cell height higher than the default? Some modification in ViewWillAppear maybe?